# Making an iOS library or framework with C# and MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios

I'd like to look into the possibility of building a (cross-platform) library (no UI) using MonoTouch. From what I've seen so far, the Mono project looks like a very good candidate for such an endeavor.

Can MonoTouch compile libraries or frameworks for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can compile them for use within MonoTouch apps for iOS, however don't expect it to compile into a native library that an obj-c application can then utilize...

Answer (score 1):

checking here:

http://xamarin.com/monotouch

> **CROSS PLATFORM**
>
> Easily share code between iOS, Android and Windows Phone 7.

and then:

> **C# & .NET**
>
> Everything you love about .NET, including LINQ, Delegates and Events.

so apparently the answer is yes :)

also check this one: http://blog.xamarin.com/2011/10/12/monotouch-5-with-ios-5-support/